# Setting resource limits for multiple services based on an environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We have about 40 services that run in 3 environments - dev, staging and production. We want to be able to control the resource requests/limits for each service based on the environment it's deployed in. It'd be nice to be able to set the limits in one file and sort of access them via a map as such:

Definition:

```
service1:
  prod:
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
  dev:
    resource:
      limits:
        cpu: "0.5"
service2:
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Is there a way to define a structure like the above and import that in a chart as so:

```
include "name" "env"
```

I'm new to helm templating, but my thought right now is to define a template and pass the env and name to a function that then returns the resources block. But, since this is the first time I'm working with templates, I'm a little stuck.

If I add something like this in _helpers.tpl:

```
requests:
{{- if eq .Values.global.env "dev"}}
  {{ include "resources.dev" . }}
{{- end }}
```

Then what should my template resources.dev contain, so as to be able to pass in the name of the parent chart, service1 ? If I can get the parent chart name in resources.dev, I should be able to do what I want. Am I even on the correct path here ?

Comment: Are you separating your environments by namespaces?

Comment: The environments are in different kubernetes clusters

Comment: Hello, what I would do, is to set a values.yaml with all the resources you need.
And then a specify values-prod.yaml for production that overrides the resources with production values (you may want higher resources, 3 replicas, etc). And a values-staging.yaml for staging values. Therefore, each values file has all information relative to your environment. On helm install/upgrade you can specify the values file to use

Comment: From your parent chart you can override value of your subcharts: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart

Comment: The linked question describes an approach using the `index` template function to look up the environment name key in the values.  I'd recommend the approach @François describes instead, though, with a separate values file per environment so you can `helm install -f values-prod.yaml`.